# MVC ViewModels - Can't access objects/variable passed from controller to View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am trying to pass ModelView variables from controller to views but unfortunately views not allowing me to access variables. I mention code below.

Here is the ViewModel:

```
public class AuctionViewModels
{
    public List<Auction> AllAuction { get; set; }

    public List<Auction> PromotedAuction { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the Controller action that passes the data to the View:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        AuctionViewModels vmodel = new AuctionViewModels();
        vmodel.AllAuction = service.GetAllAuction();     //If we need to send more then 1 model to views
        vmodel.PromotedAuction = service.GetPromotedAuction();
        return View(vmodel);
    }
```

Here is view:

```
@model List<DealDouble.Web.ViewModels.AuctionViewModels>

        @foreach (var auction in Model.AllAuction )
        {
                    <a href="#"><img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/700x400" alt=""></a>
        }
```

Here is Error:

```
CS1061: 'List<AuctionViewModels>' does not contain a definition for 
'AllAuction' and no extension method 'AllAuction' accepting a first 
argument of type 'List<AuctionViewModels>' could be found (are you missing 
a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Can anyone tell me what actually i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
@model List<DealDouble.Web.ViewModels.AuctionViewModels>
```

To

```
@model DealDouble.Web.ViewModels.AuctionViewModels
```

Then you'll be able to do `foreach(var auction in Model.AllAuction)`

Comment: you were 7 seconds faster!

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was searching from few hours. Finally i got answer.

Comment: @ZubairFarooq You're most welcome! glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

you have error in line:

```
@model List<DealDouble.Web.ViewModels.AuctionViewModels>
```

you pass (as a model) Class, not list. List does not contain such property as AllAuction. try to replace this line with this one:

```
@model DealDouble.Web.ViewModels.AuctionViewModels
```

Comment: Thanks, you were also helpful!

Answer (score 1):

It should just be

```
@model DealDouble.Web.ViewModels.AuctionViewModels
```

You're only passing in one instance of this object, and then iterating over the `AllAuction` property.

Answer (score 0):

You're instantiating a single object containing two fields both of which are lists:

```
    AuctionViewModels vmodel = new AuctionViewModels();
    vmodel.AllAuction = service.GetAllAuction();     /
    vmodel.PromotedAuction = service.GetPromotedAuction();
```

But treating it as if it were a list in the view

```
@model List<DealDouble.Web.ViewModels.AuctionViewModels>
```

You need to change the above to:

```
 @model DealDouble.Web.ViewModels.AuctionViewModels
```

You can then iterate over the two fields

```
@foreach (var auction in Model.AllAuction ){}
@foreach (var auction in Model.PromotedAuction ){}
```